# Creating a highscore listView that takes up half the screen - Android

Tags: android, listview

Hi i have a custom view running my game. Once the player loses it shows up with a gameover screen still part of that custom view. I want to make a highscore listview occupying the bottom half of the screen overlapping the other view. How do i go about doing this?

EDIT:

How do i populate a listview after inflating it with the viewstub? would this work :
     listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(context,R.layout.list_item,scores));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlapping but not replacing? If so..you may use a ViewStub http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

Comment: thank you very very much but i have one more question. How do i populate a listview after inflating it with the viewstub? would this work : listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.list_item,scores));?

Comment: When you inflate the ViewStub it will be replaced by the content (your ListView) of your layout. You populate the ListView like ListViews get populated. There is nothing special because of ViewStub. Nobody can say if your code works because nobody knows what type of "scores" is and also you seem to use a custom layout for the ArrayAdapter (R.layout.list_item). In that case your custom layout should have a TextView with "@android:id/text1" as id